# How to change a shopify theme name

Tags: javascript, css, content-management-system, shopify

Does any one know how I can change a Shopify theme's name? I can't seem to find the file. I tried using Wingrep to search and find the theme name but didn't come up with any results.

Comment: You say theme name, but (I know this is a bad question), you don't mean theme, right?
as in: [here](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/your-website/themes/customize#theme-settings)

Comment: I mean the name of the theme.  In your link example, the name of the theme is Johns-Apparel-Custom as seen on image #3.  How can I change that name via the theme files to something like Bobs-Clothing-Custom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!  The theme name that appears in the theme options is defined by the theme's folder's name. So if you want to give your theme a custom name, change the name of the folder before you upload the theme to Shopify.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to Rename it in theme action list.

[image]

Reference links: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/how-to-change-name-of-theme-328507