# How to edit the theme version name in shopify

Tags: shopify

I have edited the name of the theme file in Shopify, but its version still shows the original name of the theme underneath.
Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H63Uf.png) for better explanation.

Comment: Try changing the name of the folder before you upload the theme to Shopify ([refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35159448/13133349))

Comment: @AnhPC03 I have changed the name of folder before uploading but its still showing this way.

Comment: Change the details into settings_schema.json under config folder inside theme itself